# How can i traverse through the below xml response in postman to achieve all continents using loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, postman, postman-testcase

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <m:ListOfContinentsByNameResponse xmlns:m="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
            <m:ListOfContinentsByNameResult>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>AF</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>Africa</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>AN</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>Antarctica</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>AS</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>Asia</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>EU</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>Europe</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>OC</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>Ocenania</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
                <m:tContinent>
                    <m:sCode>AM</m:sCode>
                    <m:sName>The Americas</m:sName>
                </m:tContinent>
            </m:ListOfContinentsByNameResult>
        </m:ListOfContinentsByNameResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried any method? If so, describe errors you have encountered

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about xml traverse. Here what I have tried        var responseJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
var JsonFields = responseJson['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['m:ListOfContinentsByNameResponse']['m:ListOfContinentsByNameResult']['m:tContinent']['m:sName'];
//console.log(JsonFields);

JsonFields.forEach( field => {
    if (field.sName == 'Asia'){
        console.log("Field = " + field.sName);
        //pm.expect(field.text()).to.include("Asia");
        pm.expect(field.text().to.include("Successfully passed"));
        }
    });

Comment: and I got response.................................................                                      There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(pm.response.text());

jsonObject['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['m:ListOfContinentsByNameResponse']['m:ListOfContinentsByNameResult']['m:tContinent'].forEach((a)=>console.log(a['m:sName']))
```

**use xml2json to convert xml to json**